# Git - Ignorando arquivos com .gitignore

Tags: git

Alguem pode me explicar de forma clara a diferença entre o uso dos comandos abaixo no arquivo .gitignore ?

- `/pasta`
- `pasta/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você sabe que pode por o `.gitignore` em qualquer subpasta do projeto [git](/questions/tagged/git)? Eu demorei alguns anos para descobrir isso, e fiquei feliz com a descoberta.

O primeiro caso, `pasta/`, não exige que a pasta esteja no mesmo diretório do `.gitignore`. Pode ser qualquer subdiretório chamado `pasta` que será devidamente ignorado.

O segundo caso, `/pasta/` força que o diretório a ser ignorado esteja na mesma pasta do `.gitignore`. Assim, você consegue ser bem específico.

Imagine a seguinte estrutura:

```
/--+
  |
  +- dira/ --+
   |         |
   |         +- .gitignore [1]
   |         +- subdira/ --+
   |         |              |
   |         |              +- pasta/
   |         +- pasta/
   |
   +- dirb/--+
   |         |
   |         +- .gitignore [2]
   |         +- subdirb/ --+
   |         |              |
   |         |              +- pasta/
   |         +- pasta/
   +- pasta/
```

O conteúdo de `/dira/.gitignore` (indicado por `[1]`) é:

```
pasta/
```

Já o de `/dirb/.gitignore` (indicado por `[2]`) é:

```
/pasta/
```

Com isso, o projeto irá mostrar as diferenças nos seguintes diretórios `pasta/`:

- `/dirb/subdirb/pasta/`
- `/pasta/`

E ignorará os seguintes:

- `/dira/pasta/`
- `/dira/subdira/pasta/`
- `/dirb/pasta/`

Comment: Valeu cara, ficou muito clara a sua resposta. Ajudou muito!