# Preciso criar pasta mesmo que esteja no .gitignore

Tags: git

Pessoal preciso que o conteúdo de uma pasta não seja enviado para o git (até aqui tudo bem eu uso o .gitignore) mas eu preciso que a pasta seja criada. Tem como fazer isso usando somente um .gitignore na raiz do projeto.

Comment: Relacionada: [Git - como ignorar arquivos dentro de uma pasta \[duplicada\]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/356393/3774)

Comment: Relacionada: [Git - Ignorando arquivos com .gitignore](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/345899/3774)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso não pode adicionar no `.gitignore` que está no nível "acima" da pasta.

Dentro da pasta que quer que apenas fique lá vazia, crie um outro `.gitignore` com "*" para ignorar tudo que tem nessa pasta, assim por exemplo:

```
*
*/
!.gitignore
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o arquivo com um `git add`.

E se sua pasta tiver subpastas, vai precisar acrescentar os nomes no `.gitignore`, ou criar o mesmo arquivo em cada subpaasta.

Por exemplo:

```
/src
   .gitignore <- esse não deve mexer
   /subpasta-que-quer-criar
       .gitignore <- esse que deve ter o "*"
```

Comment: Eu meio que ja estou usando desta forma, achei que tivesse uma forma mais simples com um .gitignore só.

Answer (score 0):

Basta que tu coloques o nome da pasta no `.gitignore`. Por exemplo, tenho um projeto Node.js, e não quero subir a pasta `node_modules` dele. É só eu colocar no .gitignore isso:

```
node_modules/
```

a estrutura de pastas, pra saber a localização do .gitignore e da pasta ficaria assim

```
<projeto>
   .git (pasta oculta que indica que é um repositório git)
   .gitignore (arquivo com o que quero ignorar)
   node_modules (pasta que não quero subir no git)
```

Assim tu podes ignorar qualquer pasta local. Elas poderão existir na tua máquina sem problemas, suas mudanças não serão refletidas no git.

Comment: *"...mas eu preciso que a pasta seja criada." Leonardo, se fizer isso ao clonar ou fazer pull do repositório não vai criar pasta certo? não é o mesmo que já foi citado na pergunta ( *"até aqui tudo bem eu uso o .gitignore"* )?